# What is wrong with this import activity being created through this SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

## I am creating an import activity through server-side javascript.  The import is throwing an exception:

> An error has occurred: {"message":"Unable to retrieve security
>   descriptor for this
>   frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to
>   retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}

I can't figure this one out.  It seems to be something general about the import itself, or possibly a missing property.  Since this is in a server-side javascript activity in the account, it shouldn't need to authenticate. Any ideas?  Here is the code:

```
Platform.Load("core","1");

 // Data Extension
var DataExtensionName = "TempDataExtension" + GUID();
var DataExtensionConfig = {
    "Name":DataExtensionName,
    "Description":DataExtensionName,
    "CustomerKey":DataExtensionName,
    "Fields":[]
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) DataExtensionConfig.Fields[i] = {"Name":"Field" + i, "FieldType":"Text", "MaxLength":500};
var DataExtensionObj = DataExtension.Add(DataExtensionConfig);

// Gets the DataExtension as an SOAP API Object for the SOAP API ImportDefinition below.  Seemed to be a necessary workaround.
var DataExtensionObj = Platform.Function.CreateObject("DataExtension");                    
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(DataExtensionObj, "CustomerKey", DataExtensionName);


// Import Definition
var ImportDefinition = Platform.Function.CreateObject("ImportDefinition");
var ImportDefinitionName = "TempImportDefinition" + GUID();
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "Name", ImportDefinitionName);
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "Description", ImportDefinitionName);
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "CustomerKey", ImportDefinitionName);
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "HeaderLines", 0);
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "AllowErrors", 1);
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "DestinationObject", DataExtensionObj);
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "UpdateType", "Overwrite");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "FileSpec", "subscribers.txt");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "FileType", "CSV");

var FileTransferLocation = Platform.Function.CreateObject("FileTransferLocation");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(FileTransferLocation, "CustomerKey", "ExactTarget Enhanced FTP");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "RetrieveFileTransferLocation", FileTransferLocation);
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "FieldMappingType", "MapByOrdinal");

for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++){

    FieldMap = Platform.Function.CreateObject("FieldMap");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(FieldMap, "DestinationName", "Field" + i);
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(FieldMap, "Item", i);
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(ImportDefinition, "FieldMaps", FieldMap);

} 

var AsyncResponse = Platform.Function.CreateObject("AsyncResponse");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(AsyncResponse, "ResponseType", "email");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(AsyncResponse, "ResponseAddress", "mmcnally@listengage.com");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(ImportDefinition, "Notification", AsyncResponse);

var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0];
var CreateResults = Platform.Function.InvokeCreate(ImportDefinition, StatusAndRequestID);
```

Comment: I researched this online and found that it may be a DLL issue.  Should ExactTarget take a look at this? Citation: http://forums.textcontrol.com/showthread.php?325183-Unable-to-retrieve-security-descriptor-for-this-frame

Comment: Here is more on the DDL issue. Looks like a .Net upgrade is required to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727888/exception-unable-to-retrieve-security-descriptor-for-this-frame-exception

Comment: Hi, do you remember about how you solved this issue ? I'm facing the same one currently...

Comment: @Michael This response may be very late but it look like the CustomerKey of the import definition you are trying to create is longer than 36 chars limit. The some issue goes for CustomerKey of the data extension