# Why is this QueryDefinition not working with InvokeCreate via SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, ssjs

I have a QueryDefinition that I am creating through server-side JavaScript.  The query is not being created through the InvokeCreate method, though all appears to be well with the code.  Please take a look at this error:

> ListID: 0   Index: 2
>    - from OMMCommon -->
>
> --- inner exception 3---
>
> Jint.JintException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this
>   frame. Line: 21 Char: 0 var CreateResults =
>   Platform.Function.InvokeCreate(Query, StatusAndRequestID)
>    - from Jint

And here is the code that I am working on:

```
Platform.Load('core', '1');
var DataExtensionName = "Subscribers";

var Query = Platform.Function.CreateObject("QueryDefinition");
var QueryName = "TempQuery" + GUID();
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(Query, "Name", QueryName);
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(Query, "Description", QueryName);
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(Query, "CustomerKey", QueryName);
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(Query, "TargetUpdateType", "Overwrite");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(Query, "TargetType", "DE");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(Query, "QueryText", "SELECT GUID() AS SubscriberKey, * FROM " + DataExtensionName);

var QueryDE = Platform.Function.CreateObject("InteractionBaseObject");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(QueryDE, "Name", "Subscribers");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(QueryDE, "CustomerKey", "Subscribers");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(Query, "DataExtensionTarget", QueryDE);

var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0];
var CreateResults = Platform.Function.InvokeCreate(Query, StatusAndRequestID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simpler way to go about this.  It's mentioned on [this SFMC help page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/query_definition_server_side_javascript_functions/).

Did you intend to overwrite the source data extension in your example?  Your selecting from `Subscribers` and writing to `Subscribers`.

Your `SELECT` statement may be referencing `SubscriberKey` twice, since you included `*`.  I'd verify the syntax of your query in the platform, just to make sure.

Also, T-SQL uses the `newid()` function to generate a GUID.

Here's a script I got to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var queryDef = {
    Name : "TempQuery" + GUID(),
    CustomerKey : "TempQuery" + GUID(),
    TargetUpdateType : "Overwrite",
    TargetType : "DE",
    Target : {
        Name : "Subscribers2",
        CustomerKey : "Subscribers2"
    },
    QueryText : "SELECT newid() as Subscriberkey, emailaddress, field1 FROM Subscribers"
};

var status = QueryDefinition.Add(queryDef);
Write("<br>status: " + Stringify(status));

</script>
```

Output:

```
status: "OK"
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for adding some good points of information.  I took your query solution and ran it in Automation Studio as an SSJS Activity.  The automation ran successfully, but I don't see the record in Interactions > Query.  Are you able to see it on your end?  If yes, what could cause the record not to show on my end?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it did show in the query listing.  I just ran it from a landing page, not an Automation.  I created `Subscriber2` and set it as the target data extension.  Did you do that part?

Comment: That was the answer.  Thanks a bundle!  Listen, I'm having a similar problem with creating an import activity.  Since there's no SSJS native support for import creation, I had to defer to the SOAP API through SSJS using the Platform.Function calls.  Not sure if you could help me with that?  Here is the other question I'm eager to solve: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72844/what-is-wrong-with-this-import-activity-being-created-through-this-ssjs?rq=1